# GraphQL - how to specify maximum String lengths in schema

Tags: graphql

I want to tell GraphQL that my 'serialNumber' field is a String with a length of between 1 and 20 characters. I know to use the ! in the schema to make a field Required, but can I tell GraphQL that there is also a maximum field length?

If I pass a null value in for a required String field, GraphQL will not accept it. I want it to behave the same way when it is passed a string that is longer than the maximum allowed length.

I have looked at doing this two ways: 1) Add a 'maxlength' attribute to the field definition in the schema.graphql file. or 2) Create a new type and assign it a maximum length.

I can't find any information on how to do it. Is is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible to implement using GraphQL custom types.
You can define a type for each maximum length you want:

StringMaxLenTypes.js:

```js
const logToConsoleToHelpMeUnderstand = false;
const { GraphQLScalarType, Kind } = require('graphql');
const parseStringMaxLenType = (value,maxLength) => {
  logToConsoleToHelpMeUnderstand && console.log('Checking variable passed to a query is a string and max ' + maxLength + 'chars',value)
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    if (value.length <= maxLength) {
      return value;
    } else {
      throw new Error('parseCi' + maxLength + 'Type: String must not be more that ' + maxLength + ' characters. It is ' + value.length + ' characters');
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error('parseCi' + maxLength + 'Type: value must be of type String. It is of type \'' + typeof value + '\'');
  }
}
const parseStringMaxLen20Type = value => { return parseStringMaxLenType(value, 20) };
const parseStringMaxLen25Type = value => { return parseStringMaxLenType(value, 25) };
const parseStringMaxLen50Type = value => { return parseStringMaxLentype(value, 50) };
const parseStringMaxLen255Type = value => { return parseStringMaxLentype(value, 255) };
const parseStringMaxLen500Type = value => { return parseStringMaxLentype(value, 500) };


const serializeStringMaxLenType = (value, maxLength) => {
  /** the serialize methods are called when data is going to be sent to the client. This can return anything
   * of any type, as it will end up as JSON, but we check what is coming back from the database is a string 
   * and not too long.
   */
  logToConsoleToHelpMeUnderstand && console.log(`Checking value '${value}' is at most ${maxLength} chars before serialising for output from graphQL to a client (the OCCP gateway is the client)`);
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    if (value.length <= maxLength) {
      return value;
    } else {
      throw new Error('serializeCi' + maxLength + 'Type: String must not be more that ' + maxLength + ' characters. It is ' + value.length + ' characters');
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error('serializeCi' + maxLength + 'Type: value must be of type String. It is of type \'' + typeof value + '\'');
  }
};
const serializeStringMaxLen20Type = (value) => { return serializeStringMaxLenType(value,20) };
const serializeStringMaxLen25Type = (value) => { return serializeStringMaxLenType(value,25) };
const serializeStringMaxLen50Type = (value) => { return serializeStringMaxLenType(value,50) };
const serializeStringMaxLen255Type = (value) => { return serializeStringMaxLenType(value,255) };
const serializeStringMaxLen500Type = (value) => { return serializeStringMaxLenType(value,500) };

const parseLiteralStringMaxLenType = (ast, maxLength) => {
  logToConsoleToHelpMeUnderstand && console.log('checking Abstract Syntax Tree value (these come from parameters in GraphQL queries) is not more than ' + maxLength + ' chars long',ast);
  // For input payload i.e. for mutation. ast stands for abstract syntax tree, which is the type of 
  if (ast.kind === Kind.STRING) {
  // Note the parseStringMaxLenType function throws errors, or returns a valid value, so there is no need to throw errors here.
    return parseStringMaxLenType(ast.value, maxLength)
  } else {
    throw new Error()
  }
};

const parseLiteralStringMaxLen20Type = (ast) => { return parseLiteralStringMaxLenType(ast, 20) }
const parseLiteralStringMaxLen25Type = (ast) => { return parseLiteralStringMaxLenType(ast, 25) }
const parseLiteralStringMaxLen50Type = (ast) => { return parseLiteralStringMaxLenType(ast, 50) }
const parseLiteralStringMaxLen255Type = (ast) => { return parseLiteralStringMaxLenType(ast, 255) }
const parseLiteralStringMaxLen500Type = (ast) => { return parseLiteralStringMaxLenType(ast, 500) }

const StringMaxLen20Type = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'StringMaxLen20Type',
  description: 'String up to 20 Chars',
  serialize: serializeStringMaxLen20Type,
  parseValue: parseStringMaxLen20Type,
  parseLiteral: parseLiteralStringMaxLen20Type,
});

const StringMaxLen25Type = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'StringMaxLen25Type',
  description: 'String up to 25 Chars',
  serialize: serializeStringMaxLen25Type,
  parseValue: parseStringMaxLen25Type,
  parseLiteral: parseLiteralStringMaxLen25Type,
});

const StringMaxLen50Type = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'StringMaxLen50Type',
  description: 'String up to 50 Chars',
  serialize: serializeStringMaxLen50Type,
  parseValue: parseStringMaxLen50Type,
  parseLiteral: parseLiteralStringMaxLen50Type,
});

const StringMaxLen255Type = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'StringMaxLen255Type',
  description: 'String up to 255 Chars',
  serialize: serializeStringMaxLen255Type,
  parseValue: parseStringMaxLen255Type,
  parseLiteral: parseLiteralStringMaxLen255Type,
});

const StringMaxLen500Type = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'StringMaxLen500Type',
  description: 'String up to 500 Chars',
  serialize: serializeStringMaxLen500Type,
  parseValue: parseStringMaxLen500Type,
  parseLiteral: parseLiteralStringMaxLen500Type,
});

module.exports = {StringMaxLen20Type, StringMaxLen25Type, StringMaxLen50Type, StringMaxLen255Type, StringMaxLen500Type };
```

Then you need to define each of these types in your grapql.shema
schema.graphql:

```
scalar StringMaxLen20Type
scalar StringMaxLen25Type
scalar StringMaxLen50Type
scalar StringMaxLen255Type
scalar StringMaxLen500Type
type YourOtherTypes {
  id: ID!
  canUseAboveTypesLikeThis: StringMaxLen50Type
}
```

And import them into your resolvers.js, and define them in the resolver object passed to your graphQL server :
resolvers.js:

````
...
...
const {StringMaxLen20Type, StringMaxLen25Type, StringMaxLen50Type, StringMaxLen255Type, StringMaxLen500Type } = require('StringMaxLenTypes.js');```
...
module.exports = {
Query: {...},
Mutation: {...},
StringMaxLen20Type,
StringMaxLen25Type,
StringMaxLen50Type,
StringMaxLen255Type,
StringMaxLen500Type
````

This will then apply the same strict checking that GraphQL does all its data types to the maximum lengths.

Comment: with directives you can use any/dynamic length

Comment: thanks @xadm but I chose not to use directives cause I read they are not part of the GraphQL standard, and hence are implementation dependant. Is that your understanding?

Comment: apply a few directives to one field vs define thousands possible types? types looks ugly for api consumer? your solution is equally implementation based - needs recreation when moved to other server

Comment: ... and directives are in graphql specs

Comment: @xadm you are right, directives are mentioned the current release of the spec: http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Language.Directives . The working draft elaborates a little: "GraphQL implementations should provide the ```@skip``` and ```@include``` directives.", and "must provide the ```@deprecated```..". It says we "may provide additional directives" but I don't take that to mean ```@length``` will be implemented in all compliant servers.

Comment: implementing this as directives makes api much more universal - implementing as hardcoded types is rather naive/basic solution - what if you'll need length 200 (180, 30, whatever not already defined) and server doesn't have this? supporting this (requests) would be a pain - solution for a few use cases instead of the whole class

Comment: In my use case I am validating validating requests that must meet the specs defined in an RFC. It defines these 5 string types only (and uses integer and boolean and some ENUMS). These types allow the graphql.schema types to be called the same as it is called in the RFC, makes reading it consistent and precise to read. I see what you are saying, but this will be reusable across all compliant GraphQL servers, whereas the length(20) directive may not be. Horses for courses I guess.

Answer (score 6):

You can use directives:

```
directive @length(max: Int!) on FIELD_DEFINITION

input Payload {
  name: String! @length(max: 50)
}
```

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that `@length` only supported by Apollo.

Answer (score 1):

There is no place for this type of specification in graphql (types) definitions.

You can use directives but they are not supported (and not standarized) by all graphql servers - it's left to specific **implementation** details - **check your server docs**.

For single fields **you can simply apply this logic inside mutation resolver** - just throw an error if conditions (input string length between 1 and 20) not met.